I am getting this error very time when i do a node js project
pls solve the error @everone
Error: Cannot read file 'tsconfig.json'
I'm experiencing an issue with the TypeScript compiler (tsc) when trying to build my project. When I run the command 'tsc -b', I receive the following error: error TS5083: Cannot read file 'C:/Users/HP/Documents/Chess/tsconfig.json'.
Found 1 error.
I've checked the file path and it seems correct. The 'tsconfig.json' file exists in the specified location. I'm not sure what's causing the issue.

You have not actually shown us the file exists & is readable by the user.

This is near useless title for a problem. Please consider editing it and adding your debug information as syntax highlighted text to the question instead of a screenshot.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The tsconfig.json file has to be inside the Chess (root) folder instead of the src folder, your typescript compiler has no idea where to get the configuration from.
